# Convert 2D array into one string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am calling (iteratively) values in an object: each key is an integer and each value is a list of emails. I would like to call the list of emails as one continuos string, as in

"PersonOne@Domain.com, PersonTwo@Domain.com, PersonThree@Domain.com"

rather than

[PersonOne@Domain.com, PersonTwo@Domain.com, PersonThree@Domain.com]

so that I can use the [MailApp.sendEmail class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) in Google Apps Script. How might I convert/correctly call the list of emails so that they are recognized by the MailApp Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var arr = ['email1@domain.com', 'email2@domain.com', 'email3@domain.com']

var str = arr.join(', ');

Now, str = 'email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com, email3@domain.com';